# rspecでfactorybotのcreate_listを使用したテストが通らない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

`spec/factories/projects.rb`
のtraitを参考にusers.rbでuserが作成されるたびに5件のプロジェクト作成されるように設定したいのですが、エラーが出力され上手く動作しないです。

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :project do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Test Project #{n}" }
    description "Sample project for testing purposes"
    due_on 1.week.from_now
    association :owner
  end

  # メモ付きのプロジェクト
  trait :with_notes do
    after(:create) { |project| create_list(:note, 5, project: project) }
  end
```

`spec/factories/users.rb`

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user, aliases: [:owner] do
    first_name  "Aaron"
    last_name  "Summer"
    sequence(:email) { |n| "tester#{n}@example.com" }
    password   "dottler-nouveau-pavilion-tights-furze"
  end

  # これが上手く動作しない
  trait :with_projects do
    after(:create) { |user| create_list(:project, 5, user: user) }
  end
end
```

`spec/models/user_spec.rb`

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe User do
  # テストに失敗する
  it "can have many projects" do
    user = FactoryBot.create(:user, :with_projects)
    expect(user.projects.length).to eq 5
  end
end
```

エラー内容

```
Failure/Error: after(:create) { |user| create_list(:project, 5, user: user) }
     
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `user=' for #<Project:0x0000560f854226e8>
       Did you mean?  user_id=
```

詳しい方見て頂けないでしょうか？宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0):

```
factory :user, aliases: [:owner] do
  # ~~~
  trait :with_projects do
    after(:create) { |user| create_list(:project, 5, user: user) }
  end
end
```

とfactory do endの中に入れるとよさそうです

Comment: すいません `end` 付け忘れてました。 `FactoryBot` 内には定義されています。一応 `factory`の中に定義もしてみたのですが、同じエラーが出力されました。

Answer (score 0):

修正前

```
    after(:create) { |user| create_list(:project, 5, user: user) }
  end
```

修正後、上手く動作した。
projectのモデルは `owner` で関連付けられているから `owner` を使用する必要があった。

```
    after(:create) { |user| create_list(:project, 5, owner: user) }
  end
```

指定する値を間違えていた。